# Class initialization in exposed method using *args and **kwargs vs. using make function

Tags: python, interface

I am working on a method that collects (statistical) information on three quantities (called `A`, `B` and `C` here for simplicity) by looking through certain contents of one or more files. The whole thing is more or less equivalent to the following piece of code:

```
def get_statistics(self, file, some_option = True):
    A_list = list()
    B_list = list()
    C_list = list()
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            A, B, C = self._analyze(line, some_option)
            A_list.append(A)
            B_list.append(B)
            C_list.append(C)
    return A_list, B_list, C_list
```

This is easy to understand and works fine (except that maybe you'd want to point out that repeated `append`ing ist not so efficient, but that's not the point of the question) but has the disadvantage of producing *huge* lists `A_list`, `B_list` and `C_list`. In fact, when looping over several files, the lists may become so large that I need to worry if they fit into memory without causing problems.

Typically, the user of this method will not be interested in the full data set, however, but will only need some statistical information. Maybe the user only wants mean and variance of the quantities or is interested in plotting a histogram to visualize the data. Well, easy enough, let's just modify the signature of the method and allow for providing custom classes to collect the data of interest. I will only interact with these classes by calling their `append()` method and the user can decide what that method does. For instance, it could just sum all incoming values and count their number to calculate the mean when needed. My modified method might look like this:

```
def get_statistics(self, file, some_option = True, A_cls = list, B_cls = list, C_cls = list):
    A_store = A_cls()
    B_store = B_cls()
    C_store = C_cls()
    ...
    return A_store, B_store, C_store
```

This approach gives the user flexibility to decide, how much of the potentially huge dataset shall be stored. If the arguments of `A_cls`, `B_cls` and `C_cls` are omitted, the functionality of my first method is restored. Now considering the example of a user who wants to plot a histogram, there will be the need to pass initialization arguments to those classes like bin size or number of bins. Okay, so let's add a way to pass through initial arguments to those classes:

```
def get_statistics(self, file, some_option = True, A_cls = list, A_args = [], A_kwargs = {}, B_cls = list, B_args = [], B_kwargs = {}, C_cls = list, C_args = [], C_kwargs = {}):
    A_store = A_cls(*A_args, **A_kwargs)
    B_store = B_cls(*B_args, **B_kwargs)
    C_store = C_cls(*C_args, **C_kwargs)
    ...
    return A_store, B_store, C_store
```

Wow, suddenly I have bloated my initially easy-to-read function with *eleven* arguments plus `self`! Granted, most of them have reasonable default values, but still this seems like a nightmare both to code and to document.

So how can I keep my interface somewhat tidy? One option would be to omit the possibility to pass initialization arguments and have five arguments only, which I deem tolerable. Then, the user would need to make use of a closure to have this feature restored:

```
def make_A_helper(A_cls, *args, **kwargs):
    def make_A():
        return A_cls(*args, **kwargs)
    return make_A
A_helper = make_A_helper(A_cls, *some_args, **some_other_kwargs)
```

Passing `A_helper` to my method would then sneak in `some_args` and `some_other_kwargs`, which a user may have defined, but this appears cumbersome and annoying to code every time. I feel that a user would naturally ask, why he cannot just pass `some_args` and `some_other_kwargs` directly to my method. So what would be a good approach to handle situations like this?

**TL; DR:** Python offers the opportunity to have a user influence the behaviour of a piece of code by passing classes as arguments to functions and have the internals of these classes treated like a black box. What is the best way to implement a function with this feature without having lots of `*args` and `**kwargs` passed around? Is it acceptable to have the user write a make function as a class generator? Are there better approaches like providing some sort of `register()` method to make these classes known to the code that is supposed to use them?

Comment: What prevents you from having three simple reader functions to extract A, B, and C from a file? There is little case for a class in your code, as there is no state to store, really.

Comment: Good point, thing is that I left out all these details on purpose. Splitting up the extraction of A, B and C would lead to a 3-fold increase of computation time, since two of them come for free, when you calculate the other. Also, `self._analyze()` *does* use internal state a lot. Changing the properties of the class basically changes how you look at the data. I see your point, but I'd strongly vote for having a class (since there is internal state) and having a single method (since A, B and C are strongly coupled).

Comment: Hope it is not a way of reading a csv file. ) Your design is probably a reader class/function that takes a stream of lines as an input (it is cleaner than reading a file inside) and yields A, B and C for further processing/accumulation. This way I see `self._analyze()` becoming `Reader(incoming_stream).iterate()` or `yield_parsed_values(incoming_stream)` depending on how much of internal state is used. This limits responsibility of a parsing routine and more easliy testable. you can later integrate it in a bigger class.

Comment: Not a CSV, I can assure you. :-) Actually data stored in some binary format, chunks of it put into `numpy` arrays and processed to get A, B and C. In essence the `Reader(incoming_stream).iterate()` approach, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer here is to let the user pass objects instead of classes, ie:

```
class Something():
    def get_statistics(self, file, some_option=True, acollector=None, bcollector=None, ccollector=None):
        if acollector is None:
            acollector = list()
        if bcollector is None:
            bcollector = list()
        if ccollector is None:
            ccollector = list()

        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                A, B, C = self._analyze(line, some_option)
                acollector.append(A)
                bcollector.append(B)
                ccollector.append(C)
        return acollector, bcollector, ccollector
```

Another solution would be to provide an iterator instead and let the user do whatever with `A, B, C`

```
def iterfile(self, file, some_option=True):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield self._analyze(line, some_option)
```

then the user can collect the infos itself:

```
something = Something()
for a, b, c in something.iterfile("a/file.ext"):
    do_something_with(a, b, c)
```

The nice point here is that memory usage is not your problem anymore, but the user's xD

FWIW you can combine both by reimplementing `get_statistics()` based on `iterfile()` hence preserving compatibility:

```
    def get_statistics(self, file, some_option=True, acollector=None, bcollector=None, ccollector=None):
        if acollector is None:
            acollector = list()
        if bcollector is None:
            bcollector = list()
        if ccollector is None:
            ccollector = list()
        for A, B, C in self.iterfile(file, some_option):        
            acollector.append(A)
            bcollector.append(B)
            ccollector.append(C)
        return acollector, bcollector, ccollector
```

Comment: In some sense, passing an object instead of a class is the same as passing a make function: The user needs to specify all `*args` and `**kwargs` before calling my method. But I agree that passing an instance yields cleaner code. The iterator approach is nice, of course, but for me has the downside that there are many many iterations per second and so I'd impose on the user to make their consumer fast to not slow down execution dramatically.

Comment: The iterator can allow for faster execution by  allowing the user to 1/ avoid the python for loop (which can't be optimized) and use any higher-level and more optimized constructs (`map`, `filter`, list comprehension etc), 2/ optimize further by just ignoring values they don't care about, 3/ optimize memory use by not necessarily storing all values, etc etc...  Actually your for loop / append solution is far from optimal wrt/ both space and time.

Comment: Your observation is correct, but as mentioned in my question and comments, in the real code there is no such loop, but instead a numpy array and some number crunching. I don't think that list comprehensions are faster than the C optimized numpy vector operations, but I may be mistaken in that point. Concerning points 1/ and 2/ that you mention, you are right, of course.

Comment: Point 3 is still valid when users don't need the full dataset.  And I can only comment on the code you posted actually - we don't know where you use numpy arrays nor what for.